# Access database on Server with localhost node Project

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vps

I have bought a VPS for my website. I have built a small project with vue and node.
In this I used postgresql that is working fine on localhost.

I want to change my database from localhost to the server database where I have installed postgres and made a database and table.

My db.js file looks like this:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  password: "root",
  database: "todo_database",
  host:"45.111.241.15",
  port: 5432
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Then I tried to send form data from the localhost vue page and it gave the following error:

```
error connecting db Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 45.111.241.15:5432
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '45.111.241.15',
port: 5432
```

I do not have much knowledge about this and how to solve this.
Can you please guide me what should I do to connect with my server db?

Comment: does `psql -h 45.111.241.15 -p 5432 -U postgres` even work? First verify you can get to postgres "the normal way" using a remote connection with `psql` before looking at whether code libraries are the problem. It's entirely possibly you forgot to clear the `postgres` user for connections, for example (also: never keep the default user roles. Make a new one with exactly the rights it needs, and nothing else. For added security, have three different roles, one for read only, and one with read/write, and one with admin-enough powers for _just_ the database(s) you need)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the reply but  I ran this `psql -h 45.111.241.15 -p 5432 -U postgres` and got the error `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "45.111.241.15" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`  but `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres` is running properly

Comment: then this is jst a normal "how do I configure postgres" question, which has plenty of answers all over the web. not nodejs or vps related

Answer (score 0):

I follow these steps and it worked:

edit your /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf and change

## Connection Settings -

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

In /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

## IPv4 local connections:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

Now restart your DBMS

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now you can connect with

```
psql -h hostname(IP) -p 5432 -U postgres
```